# Error 'Image' has no attribute 'open' but it should

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Im using PIL and TKinter to open an image. I do not understand why I'm getting this error

```
import os
import random
from PIL import Image
import time
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def timer(mins):
    time.sleep(mins * 60)

def anmuViewer():
    random_pic = (random.choice(os.listdir("D:/de_clutter/memez/anmu")))
    openPic = Image.open('D:/de_clutter/memez/anmu/' + random_pic)
    openPic.show()

    timer(3)

start_btn = Button(root, text = "Start", command = anmuViewer)
start_btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

what should happen is a tkinter window should pop up with only a button called "start". When I click that button, a new window with the image should pop up. instead I get this error

```
line 17, in anmuViewer
    openPic = Image.open('D:/de_clutter/memez/anmu/' + random_pic)
AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'
```

Comment: "tkinter.Image" overwrites "PIL.Image" in your module's namespace. Avoid imports with `*`.

Comment: This is why wildcard imports shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 0):

Like Michael Butscher said,

> "tkinter.Image" overwrites "PIL.Image" in your module's namespace.  Avoid imports with `*`

But if you must use a wildcard import, importing tkinter before PIL should solve your problem

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import random
from PIL import Image
import time
```